# How to make an input accept spaces?

Tags: python, arrays, append, range

I need a program **in Python**, which would ask a user to enter multiple numbers into one line, each number separated by a space. Like `Enter your numbers: 2 1 5 8 9 5` and I need for it to print out `[2, 1, 5, 8, 9, 5]`

But the program I made so far does not accept spaces, how do I change that? Also is there a way to make the number go in order like from smallest to biggest?

Here's what I have so far:

```
elx = []

el = input("Enter your numbers: ")
for i in el:
    if el.isdigit():
        elx.append(el)
        break
    if not el.isdigit():
        print ("Number is invalid")
        continue

print (elx)
```

Comment: My answer is in Python, so there's no need for the bold.

Comment: In your example, `el` is not a list of numbers but the string `'2 1 5 8 9 5'`. So you can just split that string by spaces `el.split(' ')`

Answer (score 2):

Just split by whitespace, using a list comprehension to check if the strings are made of numbers:

```
nums = sorted([int(i) for i in input().split() if i.isdigit()])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a try/except and sorted:

```
while True:
    el = input("Enter your numbers: ")
    try:
        elx = sorted(map(int, el.split()))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input")
```

If a user can enter negative numbers then isdigit is going to fail.

Also if a user enters `1 2 3 f 5` I think it should be considered a mistake not ignored.

Comment: Why are you sorting? The list is in the same order as the string.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi, have you read the question? *Also is there a way to make the number go in order like from smallest to biggest*

Answer (score 1):

```
s = input('Gimme numbers! ') # '1 2 3'
s = list(map(int, s.split()))
print(s) # [1, 2, 3]
```

This generates a list of strings which contain the numbers (`s.split(' ')`), which are in turn converted to ints by the map.

Finally, to sort the list, use `sort(s)`.

Edit: as stated in the [official doc](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), using `split(sep=' ')` would throw an exception if some numbers were separated by two spaces, because in that case an empty string would be generated by the split (`'1  2'.split(' ') == ['1', '', '2']`), and the `int()` would fail to convert it.

Thanks to Padraic Cunningham for pointing this out!

Comment: try `s = list(map(int, "1   2".split(' ')))`, you should not pass anything to split.

Comment: You're right, passing the `sep` parameter throws an exception if some numbers are separated by two spaces. I'll edit my answer. Thanks!